# Which types of objects should I store as variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, caching

Two jsperfs relating to the question:
[Cache-ing 'this'](http://jsperf.com/cache-this-vanilla)
[Cache-ing booleans](http://jsperf.com/cache-booleans)

I'm on Mac 10.9.  In Safari 7, Chrome 32, and Firefox 26, storing 'this' inside a variable seems to run slightly slower than not storing it.  For example:

```
function O() {
        var THIS = this;

        THIS.foo = 'foo';
        THIS.bar = 'bar';
        THIS.baz = 'baz';
}
```

was a bit slower than:

```
function O() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
    this.bar = 'bar';
    this.baz = 'baz';
}
```

Why is this? Is it because 'this' references the original object every time?

In Chrome and Firefox, storing a Boolean object and then referencing the value of that variable later seemed to run a bit faster than writing 'true' or 'false' every time (in theory, creating a new Boolean object every time.) BUT, in Safari, the opposite appeared to be true.  For example:

```
function lt() {
    if(arguments[0] < arguments[1]) return true;
    return false;
}
```

was a bit faster (in Firefox and Chrome) than:

```
var TRUE = true,
    FALSE = false;

function lt() {
    if(arguments[0] < arguments[1]) return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

With the exception of Safari, is this because a new Boolean object is being created every time when not storing it inside a variable?  What could be the explanation as to why there was the opposite effect in Safari?

I'm inclined to think that in small bits of code, the difference would be negligible, but I'm curious if it could make a difference with which someone should be concerned when the code gets much lengthier.  I also read a question asking about performance data vs. perceived performance, where perceived performance is generally the thing to look at in these cases.

An issue with the above statistics in the jsperfs is the lack of a large data sample.  The reason I ask this question is because I'm writing a small JS library.  In that context, **what are best practices as far as 'caching' certain objects?**

Comment: "in theory, creating a new Boolean object every time" --- nope

Comment: Is return true equivalent to return new Boolean(true)?

Comment: "what are best practices as far as 'caching' certain objects?" --- there are no, implement it in a way you can maintain/support easily. When (and if) you have any performance issues - solve them.

Comment: Nope. `return true` returns a primitive type

Comment: "Why is this? Is it because 'this' references the original object every time?" -- because you're defining a variable multiple times. So defining a variable is slower than not defining. Try 1 `var foo = this` and million of reads. It should be identical to reading from `this` directly.

Comment: I should've asked that question under the first code snippet.  What I meant was, "Why is not storing 'this' faster?  Is it because 'this' is always a reference back to the original object and not a redefinition of a variable?"  Also, does your answer mean that because I'm storing 'this' as 'THIS', it is defining 'THIS' over and over again?

Comment: "Is it because 'this' is always a reference back to the original object and not a redefinition of a variable?" --- nope. It's because creating a variable is slower than not creating. As soon as it's the same reference it doesn't matter for js engine - they don't care of what name you use to access it. "Also, does your answer mean that because I'm storing 'this' as 'THIS', it is defining 'THIS' over and over again? " --- yep, jsperf runs the same code multiple times, so you're measuring not the time of accessing properties, but the time spent for creating a var + accessing props.

Comment: Your jsperf tests are flawed. You're setting up/overwriting the constructor(s) each time, which is not the part that you want to measure.

Comment: Check http://jsperf.com/cache-booleans/2 and http://jsperf.com/cache-this-vanilla/4 - uncached is definitely faster due to less scope lookup and variable creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question as to why safari behaves differently from Firefox and Chrome in these examples, because the reason is very implementation-dependent and I'm not familiar with the source codes of either of these browsers; nor have I spent a long time trying to reverse-engineer them. But I can give you a rough sketch of how variable caching influences performance just using the ECMAScript spec:

First it's important to understand that the **this** keyword is initialized during invocation, and it's always local to your execution context, i.e. the look-up for the this keyword will terminate on the activation record of the current function invocation. So in your first example you're creating an additional local variable - double the work - leaving the execution context with following activation record (omitted other system-defined properties, e.g. arguments):

```
{ this: caller, THIS: caller };
// this: system-created property (?during function object creation or invocation?)
// caller: system-initialized value, during invocation
// THIS: user-created-and-initialized property, slows down execution
```

So in general the best **reason** to cache a *variable* is because the look-up operation is more expensive than creating a local property. Creating a local property obviously only benefits performance if it is referenced more than one time. Fore mentioned operation can be done on the scope-chain, or on the prototype-chain using the dotted look-up operation. As long as property creation is less expensive than the actual look-up operation, you can cache the property.

The best **reason** to cache a *value*, is to avoid creating the same values over and over for every invocation. The best **way** to cache a value is through an (anonymous) closure. E.g.:

```
var obj0, obj1, funExt;
obj0 = {};
obj1 = {};
funExt = (function () {
    var cachedId, cachedObj;
    // After evaluation of funExt is done these values will persist in closure,
    // avoiding value creation during the execution of returned function.
    cachedId = "extension";
    cachedObj = { prop0: myValue, prop1: myValue, prop2: myValue };
    return function (o) {
        if (o) {
            o[cachedId] = cachedObject;
        } else if (this !== window) {
            o = (this[cachedId] = cachedObj);
        }
        return o;
    };
}());
obj0.funExt();
funExt(obj1);
```

Concerning your second example I can only say that in Chrome and Firefox boolean creation is less expensive than a one-level scope look-up. Given the complexity of the example function both operations should be rather cheap.

It's also good to keep in mind that developers design javascript engines to do these in-line optimizations on the fly. So there is no guarantee that these optimizations will yield significant performance boosts. I prefer to stick to simplicity and clarity of structure when building libraries. So I use closure to either communicate that values are being shared, or that certain values remain constant. And I use variable caching if the given variable is too long or lacks clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the more deeply an object is in your object graph, the more reason to cache it. So for example: no reason to cache `this` in your example, but if you have an object `foo.bar.something.else.x` and want to use multiple times, then chances are you better off caching that into a local variable. It will be faster, and also more readable.

Another good reason to cache an object if it's multiple levels up in your scope chain. For example, when you have 4 levels of nested functions and in the innermost you want to use a variable from the global scope multiple times, it's reasonable to cache it in a local variable.

Comment: `foo.bar.some.very.long.property.lookup` has nothing to do with the scope chain.

Comment: @zord I think you're confusing the scope look-up operation with the dotted look-up operation here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I mixed up the two points I wanted to make. I edited my answer to fix it. Thanks for calling my attention to it.